# Why is my angularjs site not completely crawlable?

Tags: angularjs, seo

I have created my first AngularJS website. I have set up pushstate (html5 mode), added fragment metatag, created sitemap in google and tested "google fetch" functionality. After few days, my website is still not completely indexed by google. Google indexed only 1 url instead of 4 (my sitemap contains 4 url's). My website is [Tom IT](http://www.tom-it.be). This main page is index, but [this subpage](http://www.tom-it.be/website-app-ontwikkelaar.html) that is also in the sitemap (you can find my sitemap in sitemap.xml in the root of my domain tom-it.be), does not appear in search results. I also added robots.txt.

Answer (score 0):

Google crawlers can parse the pages that generated by SPA and appear at SERPs, but not immediately, may need several days. In my experience, use AngularJS may need 3 days, and use EmberJS need 7 days.

If your website wants to be crawled completely, the important information should put in HTML, or use other techniques, for example, prepare another page for crawlers, server pre-rendering or PhantomJS.